# Books on Market Risk for practice problems

Tags: market-risk

Are there any books with practice problems for Market Risk, with special emphasis on vanilla and exotic options?  Or should I look into old exam papers from FRM as sold by Kaplan/GARP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookup something like "free FRM exam" or "FRM exercises". Here is a free exam from GARP itself, with explanations:
http://www.garp.org/media/613028/frm%20practice%20exam052711.pdf

I hope this helps

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. The one book I heard about is "Market Risk Analysis" by  [Carol Alexander](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470997990). However I think you should try to search for some company specific materials. Sometimes big banks like Credit-Suisse or Deutche Bank publish some materials which are hard-to-find by other means.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert of market risk, but, as regards the market risk references I know, the best one and more related to the question posted above is Dynamic Hedging by N. N. Taleb.

Here below you can find the full reference:

> Taleb, Nassim. Dynamic hedging: managing vanilla and exotic options.
>   Vol. 64. John Wiley & Sons, 1997.

It concentrates the book on options trading mainly, but you can find it useful in terms of risk management too, and, so I suggest you read that by integrating with more recent papers about the topic.

Comment: Thanks. This book does not have practice problems.

Comment: Sorry @Victor123, what do you mean by practice problems? Examples, exercises or codes implementation?

Comment: Exercises, with hopefully solutions available separately

Comment: Ok, so, sorry but I misunderstood the question. In such case, the only one I can suggest is the Hull's one!